# Different name while creating in DRF for foreign key field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to use a different name for foreign key fields while creating a object using Serializers.
Suppose I have a model `A` with foreign key field `b` to model `B`. How do i this ?

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='a')

class AS(serializer.Serializer):
    b_id = ?? ## Some thing here so that b_id fills up the b field of A
    class Meta:
       fields = ('b_id')
```

I have different serializer for creation and getting details.
While getting details i use nested serializer for getting details of `B` that's why i want to use `b_id` field while specifying only id and `b` when getting data from `B`

Edit:

I tried

```
b_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='b', queryset=B.objects.all())
```

but it gives following error:

```
{
  "b_id": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received int."
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you just want the PK value, you don't need to declane anything there. It will show the id value by default.

Comment: I am using this for creation and need a custom name b_id for field b